# page forward doesn't display p:messages when using new p:autoUpdate component

Tags: jsf, primefaces, forward

After updating to PrimeFaces 6.2, I've been replacing the obsolete autoUpdate attribute of p:messages with the new p:autoUpdate child component.

In one case it is not working as before. I have a **login.xhtml** page in which if the username is not filled in it will do a page forward to itself:

```
if (username == null || username.trim().equals("")) {
    FacesMessage message = Utils.getMessageFromResourceFile("error.login.userName.required");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("loginForm", message);
    return "/login";
}
```

Within the same page, there is a p:messages that displays the error when autoUpdate is set as an attribute:

```
<p:messages id="loginMessages" for="loginForm" autoUpdate="true" showDetail="false" closable="true" showIcon="false"/>
```

But it doesn't display it anymore when replacing the attribute with the p:autoUpdate component:

```
<p:messages id="loginMessages" for="loginForm" showDetail="false" closable="true" showIcon="false">
    <p:autoUpdate/>
</p:messages>
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and solved it by returning `null` in method (instead of "/login"). I found that solution here: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=55471